# How can I remove input field from mat-datepicker and just show icon

Tags: javascript, html, angular, datepicker

I just want to remove input field and shows calendar icon only.

How can I do that?

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp3" disabled>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp3"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #dp3 disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
    <mat-label>View Calendar</mat-label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use a "mat-menu". Inside you can put a mat-calendar. Use [selected] and (selectedChange) to give value to a variable

```
<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu">
<mat-icon>calendar_today</mat-icon>
</button>
<mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu" >
      <mat-calendar style="width:15rem"  #calendar [selected]="date"
          (selectedChange)="date=$event">
      </mat-calendar>
</mat-menu>
```